# Reset objects to inital states

Tags: java, class, object

Is there a way in java to reset objects to an initial state.  I am demonstrating searches, however, when I reach a node an change the value to

```
current.visited = true;
```

then the next search run now must be equal to

```
current.visited = false;
```

which is doable except incorrect logic.

So ideally the constructing code would look like:

```
        System.out.printf ("Breadth first search...\n\n");
    breadthFirstSearchMap (Romania);

 RESET Objects here...
    System.out.printf ("Depth first search...\n\n");
    depthFirstSearchMap (Romania);

 and again  here...

    System.out.printf ("Depth limited search...\n\n");      
     depthLimitedSearchMap (Romania);
```

Comment: How do you determine initial state? Either have a reset method that does that or use `new` to make a new object.

Comment: Provide a method that resets them to their initial states? And a way to define what that initial state is? Or recreate them? What?

Comment: Manually set the state to whatever you think is the "initial" state after you're done using the variable for whatever it was you were using it for.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah i definitely over though looked  that thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface Resetable {

    public void reset();
}

class Foo implements Resetable {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use my own `reset()` method(s). Simple enough to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassObject depthFirstSearchMap;
public void blabla(){
depthFirstSearchMap = new ClassObject(Romaina);
 System.out.printf ("Breadth first search...\n\n");
breadthFirstSearchMap (Romania);
depthFirstSearchMap = new ClassObject(Romaina);
System.out.printf ("Depth first search...\n\n");
depthFirstSearchMap (Romania);
depthFirstSearchMap = new ClassObject(Romaina);
System.out.printf ("Depth limited search...\n\n");      
 depthLimitedSearchMap (Romania); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to memento  design pattern, although if imho the simplest way is to store visited flags as a `java.util.Set` of visited node id (contains operation cost 1 on any `Set` implementation) that you initiate for each search.

Otherwise Memento pattern Wiki dexcription is :

"The memento pattern is a software design pattern that provides the ability to restore an object to its previous state"